# Transporting players from Faerun to Athas (Dark Sun)

Tags: dark-sun, forgotten-realms

Am looking for some idea's on how one would send his/her current players to Dark Sun from Forgotten Realms, allowing the players to remain content & happy, keeping their precious characters due to not wishing to part with them.

And how would their current currency possibly be affected?

Some ideas I thought might work, possibly a Gate spell gone array, a random portal possibly placed within a region of wild magic.

Currency I am really unsure about. I know Athas uses a different system, where metals are extremely rare. How would you deal with their currency without robbing your players blindly?

Due to none of them being Psionic, how would you awaken their psionic abilities?

Comment: Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/10481/what-things-should-i-take-into-consideration-before-sending-my-pcs-to-athas/10482#10482

Comment: This question has a few issues. It seems to be soliciting idea generation ("how would you do X?"), and as such is primarily opinion-based; there's no way to choose a single "best" answer. In addition, you also ask a related question about how the suggested method would affect their currency... And an entirely different question about awakening psionic abilities.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

(Having seen your Ravenloft question earlier, which implies that you're familiar with that setting, I'd especially recommend the following):

**Bring them in through Ravenloft**. First have the PC enter the demiplane of dread, then have them wander through -- practically to toughen them up -- a few, more and more desert-like domains (possibly encountering a teacher of psionics on the way... or a shocking experience that wakes up their talents), and end their misty journey in [**Kalidnay**, a domain that was lifted into Ravenloft from Athas](http://www.fraternityofshadows.com/wiki/Kalidnay).

Kalidnay (and the official rules and guidelines for the domain) should serve as a fine and final stage to solve the cultural / economic issues, before letting your players **out of that domain... straight into Athas**, if they haven't had enough of the Dark Sun vibe already. :D

Comment: Awesome idea. There are a couple players wanting to experience both Ravenloft and Dark Sun. This would work out very well!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another possible way would be through the use of Spelljammers. The PCs get picked up by one, go through a checkpoint were they must exchange all their metal equipment for the Athas equivalent, then have a Spelljammer drop them off in the middle of the desert were they must fend for themselves in the harsh new environment.

Comment: What is this 'checkpoint' that you refer to?  Something in the rules?  Or something that you're inferring by use?

Comment: Spellljammers cannot get into Athas' crystal sphere. It is sealed.